# sql find duplicates in a one column or other column

Tags: sql

I'm having trouble writing a SQL query for the following requirement:

I have a table consisting of the columns: id, date(dd/mm/yyyy), phone and email. id is unique for each row in the table.

I need to find duplicates records by finding duplicates in phone **OR** email columns based on date column. 
i.e, Identify if the email **or** phone in a record already exists on a previous date. If so, mark it as duplicate.

[image: Data Table]

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: Can you explain a bit, how you are marking it as dup ?

Comment: If phone or email repeats a value it should be marked as duplicate. But, the marking should be done based on the date. the latest records with duplicate phone/email should be marked duplicate. i hope this explains my  question

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Prob do something like this:

```
 select a.id, a.date, a.phone, a.email,
 case when b.phone is not null or c.email is not null then 'Duplicate' else 'Unique' end as flag 
 from table a 
 left join table b on (a.phone = b.phone and a.date > b.date)
 left join table c on (a.email = c.email and a.date > c.date)
```

If you have dupes in the dataset across phone, email and date, this may result in multiple rows returning so you may need to a sub select in the join.

For example

```
 left join (select distinct phone, date from table) b on (a.phone = b.phone and a.date > b.date)
```

---

Original above

I've thought about it some more and you'll get duplicate rows on the join if there are previous instances of the phone or email.

This should work better:

```
select a.id, a.date, a.phone, a.email,
case when a.phone is null and a.email is null then null
when sum(case when b.phone is not null or c.email is not null then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 'Duplicate' else 'Unique' end as flag 
from table a 
left join table b on (a.phone = b.phone and a.date > b.date)
left join table c on (a.email = c.email and a.date > c.date)
group by a.id, a.date, a.phone, a.email
```

Comment: Hey, this works perfect. Thanks. May I know what to do if few field values in phone or email are empty...so, if both the fields are empty in a record then flag should be null, but if either of the fields is available then it should check according to the available field.

Comment: Made the adjustments. Also adjusted it because the original version would have created duplicate rows for you. You can basically use case when... then... else... end statements as if statements and build them up.

Comment: Great! Thank you for the help